# Spring Boot SessionFactory returning NullPointer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a native query in SpringBoot return to a DTO.
However, my SessionFactory is returning `null`.
I have read lots of questions here in SO but no one seems to help.

What am I doing wrong here?

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

**SessionFactoryConfig.class**

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SessionFactoryConfig {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf) {
        return hemf.getSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

**ReportAverageCost.class**

```
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer;
import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ReportAverageCost {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Date date;

    public List getReportAverageCost() throws Exception {
        String q = "SELECT (...)";

        SQLQuery query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(q);
        query.addScalar("date");
        ResultTransformer aliasToBean = Transformers.aliasToBean(ReportAverageCost.class);
        List result = query.setResultTransformer(aliasToBean).list();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define annotation `@Component` on your `ReportAverageCost` class.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar but it didnt worked. I found another solution and posted as answer

Answer (score 0):

This site helped me: https://blog.pranavek.com/using-hibernate-sessionfactory-in-spring-boot-app/

So me code got like this:

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
```

**ReportAverageCostRepository.class**

```
@Repository
public class ReportAverageCostRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List getReportAverageCost() throws Exception {
        String q = "SELECT (...)";

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(q);
        query.addScalar("date");
        query.addScalar("transactionIdentifier");
        query.addScalar("amount");
        query.addScalar("cost");
        query.addScalar("price");

        ResultTransformer aliasToBean = Transformers.aliasToBean(ReportAverageCost.class);
        List result = query.setResultTransformer(aliasToBean).list();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return result;
    }

}
```

**ReportAverageCostController.class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/reports/averageCost")
public class ReportAverageCostController {

    @Autowired
    ReportAverageCostRepository reportAverageCostRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{pair}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ReportAverageCost> reportAverageCost() throws Exception {
        return reportAverageCostRepository.getReportAverageCost();
    }
}
```